# "docker-compose" command to set path for docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker-compose

Reading the help by `docker-compose -h`, or [this official manual](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#command-options-overview-and-help), will give us the option `--project-directory PATH`

> docker-compose [-f ...] [options] [COMMAND] [ARGS...]
>
> --project-directory PATH    Specify an alternate working directory
>                                 (default: the path of the compose file)

But I tried to call the below command and failed - I have ensured the file at `./mySubFolder/docker-compose.yml` has already been created.

```
docker-compose --project-directory ./mySubFolder up
```

The error

> Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or anyparent.
>
> Are you in the right directory?
>
> Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml

What I did wrong? How to pass the parameter properly?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use the `-f` param instead `--project-directory` [view details](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#specifying-multiple-compose-files#specifying-a-path-to-a-single-compose-file)

> You can use -f flag to specify a path to Compose file that is not located in the current directory

```
docker-compose -f /path/to/docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: When I specify -f and the path to the docker-compose.yml I get this error: `ERROR: .PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/dcoker-test/docker-compose.yml'`

Comment: you need to include the filename `docker-compose -f project/docker-compose.yml up` instead of just the folder `docker-compose -f project up`

Answer (score 8):

I have been using both `-f` and `--project-directory` as a continuous practice and it's clear for myself.

`-f` helps find the target file if it is not in your current directory or you have multiple versions in a directory;

`--project-directory` as reference for any path-relative variables defined inside the `docker-compose.yaml` file

such as

`docker-compose --project-directory ./ -f [path/to/any/docker-compose.yaml] up -d`

Comment: This should be accepted answer because explains both flags