# Laravel error: Laravel Sail no such File or directory found

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-8

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.codemag.com/Article/2111071/Beginner%E2%80%99s-Guide-to-Deploying-PHP-Laravel-on-the-Google-Cloud-Platform),

I installed Docker and WSL2(Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS) on my windows system, as shown in image below,
[image]

When i am trying to run Laravel project using command,

```
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

Why i am getting error no such file or directory found?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Instead of:

```sh
./vendor/bin/sail up ❌
```

Use this:

```sh
bash ./vendor/laravel/sail/bin/sail up ✅
```

Comment: if you get error "Docker is not running". check which distro set default. if is docker-desktop, set you default distro (is my case Ubuntu)

Comment: what about publishing docker-compose.yml file and running docker-compose up -d?

Comment: @OzalZarbaliyev By default, [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail) passes forward any [arbitrary/unknown arguments](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/b69e7bceb09c65e4bf5a3d4169bc28275798aec7/bin/sail#L467) to the *"docker-compose"* binary. Hence you can achieve your request by [defining the *"docker-compose.yml"* file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145141/docker-compose-command-to-set-path-for-docker-compose-yml-file) in this way: `bash ./vendor/laravel/sail/bin/sail -f ~/path-to-YML-file/docker-compose.yml up -d`

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa yep you are right. There are some additional configuration with sail. we should use sail instead of directly using docker-compose

Answer (score 4):

`composer update && npm install` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

#### Step 1

In your terminal, run this to open your .bash_profile file :

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

And paste this :

```
if [ -r ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Exit and save the modification.

#### Step 2

Still in your terminal, run this to open your
.bashrc file :

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

And paste this :

```
alias sail='bash vendor/bin/sail'
```

Exit and save the modification.

#### Step 3

You can now open any Laravel project using Sail and write the following command to start it :

```
sail up
```

Or to run it on background:

```
sail up -d
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2

Comment: You can also find this in original source: https://dev.to/jeromew90/how-to-start-laravel-project-with-the-shortcut-sail-up-using-bashrc-31dl

Comment: Hi Getoar Kastrati, I tried this one but it says an error 'sail' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. what do you think was I missing?

Comment: I also tried adding it into PATH on environmental variables to access it globally and located the bin on alias sail='bash vendor/laravel/sail/bin', but seems this path is not operable file. Can you help me. Thank you